# Is there any way to recover my Asset in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

My Asset is gone for some reason. It said I have no assets in the package manager even though the last time I use Unity, it still has a lot of assets normally. I checked my asset store and it said I have no asset too. But when I tried adding the asset I have before it wouldn't add. Weird? If you know how to fix this problem please tell me.

Comment: I had this once but I don’t remember what I did to fix it. Sorry. Have a google

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could cause your assets to disappear in Unity. Here are a few possible explanations:

You may have accidentally deleted the assets from your project. You can check to see if the assets are still in your project's "Assets" folder.

You may have moved or deleted the assets outside of Unity. This could cause Unity to lose track of the assets, as it relies on the file path to locate them.

There may be a problem with your Unity project file. If the project file is damaged, it could cause assets to disappear or become inaccessible.

To fix the issue, you could try the following:

Check to see if the assets are still in your "Assets" folder. If you find them there, you can try reimporting them into your project.

If you can't find the assets in your "Assets" folder, try searching your computer for the missing assets. If you find them, you can move them back into the "Assets" folder and try reimporting them into your project.

If you are still unable to locate the missing assets, you may need to create a new Unity project and import the assets into the new project.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).